# k&R,how getchar read EOF

Tags: c, getchar

while reading from k&r i came across the following example

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int c;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
}
printf("hello");
}
```

doubt 1:when i am typing the character ctrl+z(EOF on my sys) . o/p is hello
but when i am typing the string of characters like abcdef^Zghijk
o/p is abcdef->(including the arrow)  and waiting for user to enter i/p instead of   terminating loop and print hello..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ctrl+z` is not EOF, it is just a way to tell your terminal to close the stream.

On Windows systems you need to write the `ctrl+z` as the first character of the line, otherwise the terminal considers it to be an ordinary character.

Comment: But i have doubt that if its been treated like a ordinary variable then why o/p stop after abcdef->..instead of abcdef^zjhijk