# C input - getchar()

Tags: c, windows, getchar

It's a basic question.. but had to ask. For a program like this, if the use case is 123^Z, the program doesnt terminate, even though i put an EOF at the end (Ctrl+Z). Why is that so? It's only when I put an EOF after a CR that it works. Any anwers will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include < stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, nc;

    nc = 0;
    i = getchar();
    while (i != EOF) {
        nc = nc + 1;
        i = getchar();
    }
    printf("Number of characters in file = %d\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: What platform? The `^Z` makes me think Windows, but it'd be nice if you tagged the question with your platform. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you put a CR after an EOF?

Comment: Same behaviour under linux with `^D`. Works only if on newline

Comment: The short answer is that it's just how Windows works. Note, however, that if you press F6 instead of ctrl+Z, it'll take effect even if it's in the middle of the line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [k&R,how getchar read EOF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473190/kr-how-getchar-read-eof)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows, the Ctrl-Z shortcut will only take effect if it's pressed at the start of a line.  Otherwise, the OS ignores it.  You must press "enter" or "return" to insert a newline character first.

In Unix, the Ctrl-D shortcut will flush `stdin` immediately (as mentioned in the below comments), but will not cause `getchar()` to return `EOF` unless you are on a new, blank line; same as in Windows.

From the comments (below):

> There is no "EOF character" on Unix. An EOF is simply a zero-length read. It happens at the end of ordinary files, and can be forced on a terminal by pressing the control character that's been setup in the terminal settings for EOF (usually ^D). The reason ^D "doesn't work" when the terminal buffer is non-empty is that it doesn't actually insert something in the stream; it just causes the pending read to return, but since the input length is nonzero, it's not treated as an "EOF" by the application.

This addresses a good point - no file actually *contains* `EOF` - and pressing Ctrl-D won't "insert" (as I had previously said) anything into the `stdin` stream.  It *just* flushes `stdin`.  `EOF` is a standard macro representing a notification that the end of the file was reached by a standard function.

Thanks to @R. for the explanation about `EOF`.

Comment: Not quite. While `^D` works within a line to flush STDIN, it doesn't *close* STDIN right away.

Comment: My system (Debian, admitedly not Unix), doesn't behave like you describe. Typing Ctrl+D in the middle of the line has the apparent effect of typing enter without the enter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Niklas.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is no "EOF character" on Unix. An EOF is simply a zero-length read. It happens at the end of ordinary files, and can be forced on a terminal by pressing the control character that's been setup in the terminal settings for EOF (usually ^D). The reason ^D "doesn't work" when the terminal buffer is non-empty is that it doesn't actually insert something in the stream; it just causes the pending read to return, but since the input length is nonzero, it's not treated as an "EOF" by the application.